# Word request: different-level factors?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

Let's suppose that clinical care is poor due to numerous reasons: policy-making, insufficient resources, specialists, education, non-use of standards etc.

How to say this in one word that describes the nature of these numerous reasons? Would it be correct to use different-level?

> Clinical care is poor due to numerous **different-level** reasons.

Comment: 'Different' itself obviously works; you haven't explained what you mean by 'levels' here. Is there a hierarchy of reasons?

Comment: I don't really understand what information the word ***level*** conveys here (and even ***different*** seems at least "redundant", since "numerous reasons" can't all be the same! :) But the short answer is you can't arbitrarily create such "compound adjectives". Yours is no more "valid" than, say, *...numerous **different-importance** factors* (which is "comprehensible", but not "idiomatically valid").

Answer (score 1):

You can use "due to ***multiple*** reasons": [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/multiple.html#C0-1) defines *multiple* as:

> Numerous and often varied
>
> - We have multiple options to choose from for our next holiday.

I like very much ***manifold***, though it may be considered a bit antiquated. It goes very well in formal writing though. It means:

> Many and various or having more than one layer ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/manifold.html))

See this example from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/manifold):

> many and of different types:
>
> - Our organization’s problems are manifold – too few members, too little money, and poor management.

Answer (score 0):

The question has examples of the categories of reasons: *policy-making, insufficient resources, specialists, education, non-use of standards*.

These categories illustrate the constituents of the whole clinical care process, which isn't restricted to just the patient-medic interaction.

Based on the experience of numerous visits to my local National Health Service (NHS) hospital with my elderly father, I can describe the various parts of the service one meets.

A patient being brought into A&E (Accident and Emergency) at an NHS hospital for example will be met by a triage nurse, then a porter to move the patient to the bed in the A&E, nurses to move the patient onto the bed, then a phlebotomist to collect a blood sample, A&E doctor to assess and, after being admitted to a ward, the ward nurses, pharmacists, specialists or even registrars.

Each of these groups of people may be considered at a different level with the whole healthcare organisation. The use of the term *different-level* may then allow the distinction of these separate groups of people.